# making image fill html/css

Tags: html, css

I'm aiming for a page with a collage of 4 photos;
a large one on the left taking up 50% width of the page and 100% of the height.
3 smaller photos, each taking up 50% of the width of the page but 33% of the height.

I'm running into problems with the larger image though,

my current CSS is;

```
.container {
width: 50%;
height: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
-size: cover;
}
```

and my html;

```
  <div class="container">
<img height="100%" width="100%" src="jpg"></img>
</div>
```

the image's 50% width is fine but the height is only 50%.
It's a large image(4k) and my aim was to have overflow:hidden so that it fills the container but it's not working.

How could I do this?

Edit:

I'm aiming for it to be similar to this website:

http://www.masitupungato.com/

Answer (score 1):

### Suggested Solution

In fact, it is the easiest solution

Use two different `div`s, one for the left side and the other for the right side.

The left side `div` takes the half of the container width, and contains a image

The right side `div` takes the half of the container width, and contains 3 different `div`s, each one takes 33% of this right div height, and contains an image.

Use the CSS below:

```
.container {
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    margin: auto;
}

#left {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
}

#right {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
}

.right-inner{
    width: 100%;
    height: 33%;
}

.left-inner {
  width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

### Expected output

[image]

**### Check it out.**

Answer (score 0):

You might change the height of the biggest image to fit the window of the device. Try to to set its height to "100vh", maybe it is what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

you can use display:flex; property for this purpose. it will resolve your issue dynamically.

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="big-image">
<img src="http://static.independent.co.uk/s3fs-public/styles/story_medium/public/thumbnails/image/2013/07/31/10/A-striped-field-mouse-(Apod.jpg" alt="">
</div>
<div class="small-image-wrapper">
<div class="image">
  <img src="http://static.independent.co.uk/s3fs-public/styles/story_medium/public/thumbnails/image/2013/07/31/10/A-striped-field-mouse-(Apod.jpg" alt="">
</div>
    <div class="image">
  <img src="http://static.independent.co.uk/s3fs-public/styles/story_medium/public/thumbnails/image/2013/07/31/10/A-striped-field-mouse-(Apod.jpg" alt="">
</div>
    <div class="image">
  <img src="http://static.independent.co.uk/s3fs-public/styles/story_medium/public/thumbnails/image/2013/07/31/10/A-striped-field-mouse-(Apod.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/d95hw8fq/